# Combine $sort and $gt to order and filter output in Mongo and Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Going from sql to Mongo.

The collection is like:

```
_id: ...
onix_vnr: 'TB30....._001'
```

So the items in *onix_vnr* are equally named, dated and numbered and thus sortable as text.

What i need is a pipeline with a combination of:

```
{'$gt': ['$onix_vnr', 'TB30_totaal_2023-05_095van101.onx']}
```

and

```
{'$sort': {'onix_vnr': 1 }}
```

The sorting in itself works. With $project I get output of the $cond $if $gt... , but I cannot combine this into proper output that is filtered on the condition and sorted.

The output should be something like:

```
{'TB30_totaal_2023-05_096van101.onx'}
{'TB30_totaal_2023-05_097van101.onx'}
...
```

In pymongo it would be processed with:

```
result = db[collection].aggregate(pipeline)
```

This works. Problem is finding the proper pipeline

Thanks!!!

Comment: Just put your `{'$gt': ...` in a `"$match"` stage, followed by your `"$sort"` stage, and then optionally/probably by a `"$project"` stage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @rickhg12hs:

```
{'$match': { 'onix_vnr': { '$gt': 'TB30_totaal_2023-05_095van101.onx' } }},
{'$sort': {'onix_vnr': 1 }},
{'$project':{'_id': '$onix_vnr'}}
```